# Add Radio Stream Link to a MP3 Image

Tags: html, audio, hyperlink, mp3

```html
<audio width="100" height="48" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"><source src="http://93.190.141.15:7003/live?type=.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>Your browser does not support HTML5 audio. Please update your browser to view this media content.</audio>
```

Good evening,

I am setting up a radio station website for a friend and I want to add the stream MP3 file to a image..

The image is attached...
[Listen Live Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEwkk.jpg)

and the MP3 link is attached as a snippet...

Your browser does not support HTML5 audio. Please update your browser to view this media content.

Kind regards

Gary

Comment: What browser is reporting the error?  Unless it's IE8, it should probably work:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio

Comment: Hello, there is no error. in a side bar, I have a image saying "Listen Live" and underneath, I have the MP3 stream link to the radio station. Ideally, I would love to include the mp3 to the image...

Comment: OK, I'm not sure I understand.  The image is there.  You want to make the image into a link?  <a href="foo"><img src="myimage.jpg"></a> ?